# Comparing two files and removing all whitespaces

Tags: python, bash

Is there a more elegant way of comparing these two files?

Right now I am getting the following error message: `syntax error near unexpected token (`... `diff <( tr -d ' '`.

```
result = Popen("diff <( tr -d ' \n' <" + file1 + ") <( tr -d ' \n' <" 
                + file2 + ") | wc =l", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
```

Python seems to read `"\n"` as a literal character.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part. It's fixed on the original code

Comment: BTW, you can use the builtin `difflib` module instead of using a system call

Comment: So you still get that `syntax error near unexpected token`...?

Comment: @Aran-Fey yea I do

Comment: @DeepSpace is there a `difflib` equivalent for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Oh, it's a bash syntax error, I get it. Edit: Alright, it's a _sh_ syntax error.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Not quite, I don't think.

Comment: So could you explain what output you want to get for those of us who can't read bash? What does "compare two files" mean? Do you want a list of all differences? If so, in what format? Or do you just want to know if they're identical? And what's that about removing whitespace? Should that happen before or after the files are compared?

Comment: Why are you shelling out anyway?  `import difflib` is the Pythonic way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructs you are using are interpreted by `bash` and do not form a standalone statement that you can pass to `system()` or `exec()`.

- `<( ${CMD} )`
- `< ${FILE}`
- `${CMD1} | ${CMD2}`

As such, you will need to wire-up the redirection and pipelines yourself, or call on `bash` to interpret the line for you (as @wizzwizz4 suggests).

---

A better solution would be to use something like [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) that will perform this internally to your process rather than calling on [`system()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) / [`fork()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) / [`exec()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec).

Using [`difflib.unified_diff`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff) will give you a similar result:

```py
import difflib

def read_file_no_blanks(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if line == '\n':
            continue

        yield line

def count_differences(diff_lines):
    diff_count = 0

    for line in diff_lines:
        if line[0] not in [ '-', '+' ]:
            continue
        if line[0:3] in [ '---', '+++' ]:
            continue

        diff_count += 1

    return diff_count

a_lines = list(read_file_no_blanks('a'))
b_lines = list(read_file_no_blanks('b'))

diff_lines = difflib.unified_diff(a_lines, b_lines)

diff_count = count_differences(diff_lines)
print('differences: %d' % ( diff_count ))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will fail when you fix the syntax error because you are attempting to use `bash` syntax in what is implemented as a C `system` call.

If you wish to do this in this way, either write a shell script or use the following:

```
result = Popen(['bash', '-c', 
                "diff <( tr -d ' \n' <" + file1 + ") <( tr -d ' \n' <" 
                + file2 + ") | wc =l"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
```

This is not an elegant solution, however, since it is relying on the GNU coreutils and `bash`. A more elegant solution would be pure Python. You could do this with the [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module and the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

Comment: I get the following error - `can't assign to function call`

Comment: @methuselah That's probably because you're doing something like `result() = Popen`... There was a typo in my code though; I've fixed that now.